# create list from list based on string pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a list like the example data below.  Every entry in the list follows the pattern 'source/number_something/'.  I would like to create a new list like the output below, where the entries are just the "something".  I was thinking I could use a for loop and string split on `_` but some of the texts that follow also include `_`.  This seems like something that could be done with regex, but I'm not that good at regex.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

example data:

```
['source/108_cash_total/',
 'source/108_customer/',
 'source/108_daily_units_total/',
 'source/108_discounts/',
 'source/108_employee/',
'source/56_cash_total/',
 'source/56_customer/',
 'source/56_daily_units_total/',
 'source/56_discounts/',
 'source/56_employee/']
```

output:

```
['cash_total',
 'customer',
 'daily_units_total',
 'discounts',
 'employee',
'cash_total',
 'customer/',
 'daily_units_total',
 'discounts',
 'employee']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
\d+_([^/]+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/hz2u2N/1/).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

lst = ['source/108_cash_total/',
       'source/108_customer/',
       'source/108_daily_units_total/',
       'source/108_discounts/',
       'source/108_employee/',
       'source/56_cash_total/',
       'source/56_customer/',
       'source/56_daily_units_total/',
       'source/56_discounts/',
       'source/56_employee/']

rx = re.compile(r'\d+_([^/]+)')

output = [match.group(1) 
          for item in lst 
          for match in [rx.search(item)] 
          if match]
print(output)
```

Which yields

```
['cash_total', 'customer', 'daily_units_total', 
 'discounts', 'employee', 'cash_total', 'customer',
 'daily_units_total', 'discounts', 'employee']
```

Comment: This creation of a dummy list to filter out the `None` search results is an interesting technique. I think I like it.

Comment: IMO this use of list comprehension isn't much shorter than classical approach (ordinary `for`) but is very cryptic. In Python 3.8 you may write this in much more elegant way: `output = [m.group(1) for item in lst if (m := rx.search(item))]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this without regex using only offsets and [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with `maxsplit` parameter set:

```py
offset = len("source/")
result = []
for item in lst:
    num, data = item[offset:].split("_", 1)
    result.append(data[:-1])
```

Of course, it's not very flexible, but as long as your data follow the schema, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

probably not so good and clean as compare to regex

using `list comprehension` and `split function`

```
lst = ['source/108_cash_total/',
 'source/108_customer/',
 'source/108_daily_units_total/',
 'source/108_discounts/',
 'source/108_employee/',
'source/56_cash_total/',
 'source/56_customer/',
 'source/56_daily_units_total/',
 'source/56_discounts/',
 'source/56_employee/']

res = [ '_'.join(i.split('_')[1:]).split('/')[:-1][0]  for i in lst]

print(res)

# output ['cash_total', 'customer', 'daily_units_total', 'discounts', 'employee', 'cash_total', 'customer', 'daily_units_total', 'discounts', 'employee']
```